# Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined at create:71

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

SO,
I am trying to use tinyMCE in a MVC razor view but I always get this below error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined
>       at create:71

I have included `tinyMCE.min.js` in my bundle config file. It works perfectly fine if I set razor view `_Layout` to null but when setting the `_Layout` to default Layout I get this error.

P.S: I tried this with a new MVC application it perfectly works fine there don't know what could be the problem within my main project. Your thoughts?

Update:
Here is a piece of Script which is initiate the tinymce.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Initialize your tinyMCE Editor with your preferred options

    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "modern",
        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: true,
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any script in your `_Layout` that tries to use tinyMCE before it is loaded? Kinda hard to say what the problem is without the _Layout file and Bundle config.

Comment: can you please show your current and layout page's code ?

Comment: @TeodorKurtev Please have a look at updated question

Comment: @Curiousdev The question is edited have a look at it please.

Comment: But is this doe before or after the tinyMCE loaded? Where is the library loaded? Show us the Layout scripts + the specific scripts for the view that produces the error.